# Basce64 encoding in android

Tags: android

I have to submit a base64 encoded string to my server. How to do this in android application.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides a util class for encoding and decoding Base64 strings, [android.util.Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is included in Android.util only for API level 8 and greater. If you wish to use it in an earlier API, you'll have to write your own, or find the source via Google.

Answer (score 1):

Android actually ships with support for this out of the box.

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android util package has [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by implementing a string to base64 conversion function in Java?   Android uses Java - you knew that, right?   And Google has a great search tool - I think it's located at google.com. You could use it to search for base64 code in Java, and use that in your project.